# How to create a time series data with five minutes granularity

Tags: python, time-series, pandas

I have a dataset with the format

[image: SAMPLEDATA]

I need to create a new time series data based on the above dataset with 5 minutes granularity using python, the output should look like this where eventType will be binary(0/1) for a specific event (example- 8 only)

[image: New data]

Can anybody help me to solve this?

Comment: Have you ensured that 5 minutes will be enough time for you when it comes time to make predictions? So many models start off with this type of granularity without realizing that after data collection/transforms are done on the source data, it doesn't leave enough time to create a prediction and subsequently use the prediction.

Comment: 5 minutes granularity is not for prediction, but to match with another dataset with a similar format. As we are combining data from different sources having different structures it is getting hard. So we are trying to normalizing the structure of data.

Comment: Is the question about the Python needed to create it? Or is it about some data science issue related with it?